# How to define single and multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am beginner in PHP programming. I want to know how to define single and multidimensional array in PHP.

Comment: I don't think there is a tutorial on SO for this

Answer (score 5):

There are a wide variety of ways to do this, all of which are well explained on the [relevant PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

However, in terms of some examples:

```
$singleArray = array(1, 2, 3);

$multiArray = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));
```

You of course can also use the following syntax:

```
$singleArray = $multiArray = array();

$singleArray[] = 1;
$singleArray[] = 2;
...

$multiArray[0][] = "Bob";
$multiArray[0][] = "Steve";
$multiArray[1][] = "Dave";
$multiArray[1][] = "Jack";
...
```

You can also provide you own keys (in addition to the numeric ones), such as:

```
$singleArray = array('first'=>1, 'second'=>2, 'third'=>3);
```

(Use [array_keys](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to extract the keys from such an array.)

However, if you're just starting out, you *really* want to spend a bit of time reading the excellent [online documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/index.php), practising with the [tutorials](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php), etc. as this will be a lot faster that asking a multitude of questions on SO. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Array elements in PHP can hold values of any type, such as numbers, strings and objects. They can also hold other arrays, which means you can create multidimensional, or nested, arrays.

Single dimensional Array :

```
$myArray = array(value1, value2, value3);
```

Multidimensional Array :

```
$myArray = array(
  array( value1, value2, value3 ),
  array( value4, value5, value6 ),
  array( value7, value8, value9 )
);
```

Here, the top-level array contains 3 elements. Each element is itself an array containing 3 values.

---

Basically, there are three different types of arrays:

1. Numeric array – An array with a numeric ID key.
2. Multidimensional arrays – An array containing one or more arrays.
3. Associative arrays – An array where each ID key is associated with a value.

Read here for more about these types : [Types of Arrays in PHP](http://phpguru.biz/blog/find-php-tutorial/what-is-arrays-and-types-of-arrays/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) ?

Especially the exemples, like this one :

```
$fruits = array ( "fruits"  => array ( "a" => "orange",
                                   "b" => "banana",
                                   "c" => "apple"
                                 ),
              "numbers" => array ( 1,
                                   2,
                                   3,
                                   4,
                                   5,
                                   6
                                 ),
              "holes"   => array (      "first",
                                   5 => "second",
                                        "third"
                                 )
            );
```

Comment: Thank You Boss I will be try to read the manual and take every solution